# How do I actually derive the Griffiths inequality for critical exponents?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

The Griffiths inequality for critical exponents says $$\alpha+\beta(1+\delta) \geq 2$$

I have looking for the internet for a full derivation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/critical-exponent “We now proceed to establish the Griffiths inequality.”

Comment: Can you give a bit more context/detail and define what each of the variables are?

Comment: As suggested by @G.Smith, a derivation can be found, for instance, in the book by Pathria and Beale (p. 439-441 in the third edition).